# Should 2 Activity's have separate ViewModels if the method usages don't overlap?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I have 1 `Activity` that **only** **displays** and **deletes** `Notes` from a `RecyclerView`.
I have another `Activity` that **only** **adds** and **updates** new items.

At the moment they both use the same `ViewModel` class:

```
public class NoteViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private NoteRepository repository;
    private LiveData<List<Note>> allNotes;

    public NoteViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        repository = new NoteRepository(application);
        allNotes = repository.getAllNotes();
    }

    public void insert(Note note) {
        repository.insert(note);
    }

    public void update(Note note) {
        repository.update(note);
    }

    public void delete(Note note) {
        repository.delete(note);
    }

    public void deleteAllNotes() {
        repository.deleteAllNotes();
    }

    public LiveData<List<Note>> getAllNotes() {
        return allNotes;
    }
}
```

Should I instead create 2 separate `ViewModels`, one for each `Activity`?

Comment: Do note that while using a single ViewModel class, both activities will NOT share the same instance (since ViewModel is tied to Activity lifecycle). This may lead to confusion depending on the implementation of your ViewModel

Comment: Can you post image as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on whether you are going for **simpler maintainability** or **clearer separation of concerns**.

There it nothing wrong with having a single ViewModel for both activities, but consider that a ViewModel is **supposed to *model* the *view***. 
Having some functions in the ViewModel that are not used by Activity A, and other functions not used by Activity B, does not really fit well with the idea that **the ViewModel should be a model of the functionality of the View**.

My recommendation would be two separate ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks, this is the reasoning I've been looking for!